# Owner of two oxen, fighting each other; later, both oxen die. Is the meat kosher?

Tags: torah

Can an ox killed in a fight with another be made kosher? What about hunting deer, what is the proper way to kill it in a hunt, so as to keep it kosher? I know a strangled animal is not kosher for Christians, probably because the blood was not drained out into the ground as it died. What about the hides?

Verses to consider:
Exodus 21:33-36 KJV

> <sup>**33**</sup> And if a man shall open a pit, or if a man shall dig a pit, and not cover it, and an ox or an ass fall therein; <sup>**34**</sup> The owner of the pit shall make it good, and give money unto the owner of them; and the dead beast shall be his. <sup>**35**</sup> And if one man's ox hurt another's, that he die; then they shall sell the live ox, and divide the money of it; and the dead ox also they shall divide. <sup>**36**</sup> Or if it be known that the ox hath used to push in time past, and his owner hath not kept him in; he shall surely pay ox for ox; and the dead shall be his own.

Leviticus 17:10-16 KJV

> <sup>**10**</sup> And whatsoever man there be of the house of Israel, or of the strangers that sojourn among you, that eateth any manner of blood; I will even set my face against that soul that eateth blood, and will cut him off from among his people. <sup>**11**</sup> For the life of the flesh is in the blood: and I have given it to you upon the altar to make an atonement for your souls: for it is the blood that maketh an atonement for the soul. <sup>**12**</sup> Therefore I said unto the children of Israel, No soul of you shall eat blood, neither shall any stranger that sojourneth among you eat blood. <sup>**13**</sup> And whatsoever man there be of the children of Israel, or of the strangers that sojourn among you, which hunteth and catcheth any beast or fowl that may be eaten; he shall even pour out the blood thereof, and cover it with dust. <sup>**14**</sup> For it is the life of all flesh; the blood of it is for the life thereof: therefore I said unto the children of Israel, Ye shall eat the blood of no manner of flesh: for the life of all flesh is the blood thereof: whosoever eateth it shall be cut off. <sup>**15**</sup> And every soul that eateth that which died of itself, or that which was torn with beasts, whether it be one of your own country, or a stranger, he shall both wash his clothes, and bathe himself in water, and be unclean until the even: then shall he be clean. <sup>**16**</sup> But if he wash them not, nor bathe his flesh; then he shall bear his iniquity.

Compare Deuteronomy 14:21

> Ye shall not eat of any thing that dieth of itself: thou shalt give it unto the stranger that is in thy gates, that he may eat it; or thou mayest sell it unto an alien: for thou art an holy people unto the LORD thy God. Thou shalt not seethe a kid in his mother's milk.

with Leviticus 17:12

> Therefore I said unto the children of Israel, No soul of you shall eat blood, neither shall any stranger that sojourneth among you eat blood.

Comment: In your opening paragraph you have 3 question marks. If someone asks 3 questions the problem is, "how related are they?". 3 questions about one word in one verse might be valid, if that the word in question is a focal point. Where is your focal point? Can you define one focal point?

Comment: If you're asking for a judgement if something is kosher, that really belongs on the Judaism site. Should I migrate this for you?

Comment: @C.Stroud as I was reading this I thought about methods of hunting or fresh roadkill, and was wondering what could be done to save all that food. So, if we use a high powered rifle the projectile will explode and do a lot of internal damage, but upon reaching the pray, the bleeding may have been internal. Same with roadkill. Arrows with broadheads ➳ don’t always produce a blood trail either. So, I thought the dead ox in a fight here would indicate a solution we haven’t considered. It doesn’t seem right to give any human blood filled meat, since it prohibited to all of Noah’s offspring.

Comment: I also thought there might be methods of removing blood from the butchered meat, to make it kosher. This is really bad news for a lot of people I know who hunt with guns. They are violating a basic Christian commandment. Acts 15:29

Answer (score 1):

The fact that both oxen involved in a fight will be sold, according to the Exodus quotation, so that the owners may share the value, implies that the flesh may be eaten. If the flesh could not be eaten, it would have no monetary value, and the owners would get no compensation.

Comment: The hide would be of use. And the hoofs. And the bones. The carcase still has a value even if, for whatever reason, the meat is inedible.

Comment: Not enough. The purpose of the law is evidently to equalise and limit the damage suffered by the two owners. I should have adaded that v28 does forbid eating the flesh of an ox who has killed a human, and this clause is missing in in vv35-6.

Comment: Jewish tradition holds the meat is not kosher for Jews but it may be sold to or given away to non-Jews.

Answer (score 1):

A [contemporary Jewish source](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136837/do-the-rabbis-clarify-how-long-an-ox-that-dies-in-a-pit-can-remain-there-before) clarifies the the oxen may be sold as meat to non-Jews, but Jews themselves may not eat this meat. This is based on Deuteronomy 14:21:

> You shall not eat the carcass of any animal that has died of itself; but you may give it to a resident alien within your gates to eat, or you may sell it to a foreigner.

Regarding the deer, the method of hunting is not stipulated. Instructions to prepare the meat are found in Leviticus 17:13-14:

> Any Israelite or any foreigner residing among you who hunts any animal or bird that may be eaten must drain out the blood and cover it with earth,  because the life of every creature is its blood. That is why I have said to the Israelites, “You must not eat the blood of any creature, because the life of every creature is its blood; anyone who eats it must be cut off.

Regarding the hides: "the dead beast shall be his." Since oxen are "clean," this implies that the hides may be either used personally or sold.

Comment: Trapping the clean animal goes well with some of the Psalms and Proverbs 7.22, Psalm 124.7